# Probability of choosing same multiple

Tags: probability

Will E. Pikett randomly selects an odd integer less than $100$ that is a multiple of $3$. Betty Wont randomly selects an odd integer less than $100$ that is a multiple of $5$. What is the probability that they selected the same number?

My approach:

The number of odd integers that are less than $100$ and a multiple of $3$ is $17$.
As for odd multiples of $5$, that is $10$.

There are $3$ factors in common: $15$, $45$, and $75$.

So the probability of choosing one of these three factors for Will is $\frac{3}{17}$. The probability that Betty will choose the same number is $\frac{1}{10}$ (Betty could have chosen first I suppose).

So the probability that they both chose the same factor is $\frac{3}{170}$, but obviously I'm incorrect.
Where in my work did I make an erroneous decision, and what is the result of choosing such a decision. 
Thanks.

Comment: you've just miscounted the ODD multiples of 5. Everything else is correctly argued from there.

Comment: Forgive me. I was typing off my old work. My new work did account for $10$ odd multiples of $5$. I still got the wrong answer apparently.

Comment: "Betty *Wont* randomly selects ..." reads "Betty *will* randomly ... ", I suppose.

Comment: Why do you say that this is "obviously incorrect"?

Comment: @lulu From the edit history of this question, I think OP means $\frac{3}{17\times19}$ is "obviously incorrect".

Comment: @lulu I was writing from my old work before I tried a second time at the problem. I meant to write 10 options instead of 19.

Comment: Ok...but the current version says that $\frac 3{170}$ is obviously incorrect and I don't see why.  It looks right to me.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @GNUSupporter  "Betty Wont" is her name.  It is an attempt at humour.  "Will E. Pickett / Betty Wont", get it?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes. The author typically uses whimsical names just for humor.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is okay.   It was correctly reasoned, you merely had difficulty counting / identifying the numbers.

Your approach has been to use:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(B=W) ~&=~ \mathsf P(W\in\{15,45,75\})~\mathsf P(B=W\mid W\in\{15,45,75\}) \\[1ex] &=~ \frac 3{17}\cdot\frac{1}{10}\end{align}$$

Now that the comments have lead you to the proper counts of *odd* numbers less than 100 that are multiples of three, and same of five, that is *entirely correct*.